# Как избавиться от ошибки python pocketsphinx?

Tags: python, аудио, pocketsphinx

При первой итеррации все ок, но после второго нажатия на Enter выдает код ошибки: (sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error starting stream: Invalid stream pointer [PaErrorCode -9988])
Мое предположение, что забит канал входа аудио после первой итеррации. Исли это так, дайте совет по решению проблемы или справьте если я не прав. Заранее спасибо

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
from commands import *
import phrases

model_path = get_model_path()

speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm='model\\zero_ru.cd_cont_4000',
    lm='model\\ru.lm',
    dic='model\\my_ru_dic.dic'
)
while True:
    input('Нажмите Enter, чтобы сказать команду')
    print("Слушаю вас")
    for phrase in speech:
        phrase = str(phrase)
        if phrase in phrases.for_time:
            say_time()
        if phrase == 'пока':
            exit(1)
        break
```

Comment: Может быть нужно каждый раз инстанциировать `speech` перед его итерированием? Ну то есть попробуйте `speech = LiveSpeech(...)` внести внутрь цикла `while True:`

Comment: Да, это работает, но каждый раз приходится ждать инициализации переменной speech(секунд 15) и это не очень приятно. Я думал может есть какой метод для очистки канала аудио?